# get the first property of a JSON object with json path

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a property, that is unfortunately an id, so it's difficult for me to get the further properties :

```
{
   "myprop1":1,
   "myprodid_121212":
   {
      "prop1":1,
      "prop2":2
   }
}
```

Is it possible with JSON Path to get for example the second property (without knowing the property name)? myprodid...

Comment: Which is the programming language in which you use JSON Path? Can you tag your question accordingly to make sure you get the right people interested in your question?

Comment: JSON Path is the language, the host language is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it using ES6:

```
const [key, value] = Object.entries({
        "myprop1": 1,
        "myprodid_121212":
        {
            "prop1": 1,
            "prop2": 2
        }
    }).find((entry, index) => index === 1);
```

you can easily check for the property name too by examining `entry`, see example below:

```
const [key, value] = Object.entries({
        "myprop1": 1,
        "myprodid_121212":
        {
            "prop1": 1,
            "prop2": 2
        }
    }).find(([key], index) => key.split("_")[0] === "myprodid");
```

Comment: The question is not related to JavaScript.

Comment: Right tool for the right job, huh?:) What OP need is called 'meta-programming' which is strictly speaking a complimentary functionality even with XPath.